# Mirrored Volume of Windows to Ubuntu RAID 1

Tags: raid, mdadm, 18.10, mirrors, webmin

I am dual booting Windows 10 and Ubuntu 18.10. The `D:\` Drive has a mirrored volume on another hard disk. I am trying to use `mdadm` to setup similiar mirroring on Ubuntu so that, regardless which OS I boot, the data in `D:\` drive is mirrored.

Drive `D:\` is mounted as `/dev/sda1` and the volume where it's mirrored is `/dev/sdb1`

**Questions:**

1. Can I enable mirroring without loosing any data?
2. Is it possible to mirror just a partition as opposed to entire disk?
3. If possible, will it break the mirror in Windows? (as I'm dual booting)

**What I have tried**

I have tried to use `webmin` GUI to create a mirror however I am not sure what to select here as the mounted partition does not appear on the list.

[image: webmin]

**Left:** Webmin, **Right:** Highlighted two mirrored partition and their mount location

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Probably impossible, as windows does not support mdadm. You can, however, maybe use Dynamic Disks in Windows, which is supported by Linux. [This page](https://wiki.archlinux.org/index.php/Dynamic_Disks) may give some information. I have never tried, and this is just the result of a quick google search...

Comment: @vidarlo _It is_ a dynamic disk in Windows. Thanks for the link, I will try this.